# MySQL : DELETE query return when rows are not found

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

When I try to DELETE something from MySQL database that does not exist the query returns TRUE.

I want to know when nothing is deleted. Do I need to have a previous query to find if there are rows to be deleted?

Is there a more simple way to do this? I mean, using a single query?

I'm using php to connect to the database with the mysqli_query() function.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Comment: This seems very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060325/need-to-test-if-sql-query-was-successful)?

Comment: @Big-Boii it's not that! This kind of query is successful (returns "TRUE") but no rows are affected. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27516163/4332635) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) function to find the number of records affected by the previous query.